# cron.php not upload a certain type of image

Tags: php, cron, rss

I have a CMS news site that is fed through the RSS of some sites. I'm having trouble getting use images of BING NEWS FEED. The pictures just do not work. The content is loaded through a part of the script (cron.php)

This is a custom feed I use:[Custom RSS feed from Bing News with Bing image](http://www.bingnews.xyz/feed2.php)

This is a part of the cron.php file used by my site related to images:

**...**

```
} else {
    $image = get_first_image($item->get_content());
    if (empty($image)) {
        $image = get_first_image($item->get_description());
    }
}
if (!empty($image)) {
    $filetype = strtolower(substr(strrchr($image,'.'),1));
    if (!in_array($filetype,array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif'))) {
        $filename = ''; 
    } else {
        $filename = 'image_'.time().'_'.rand(0000000,99999999).'.'.$filetype;
        $up = file_put_contents('upload/news/'.$filename,file_get_contents($image));
        $size = filesize('upload/news/'.$filename);
        list($width) = getimagesize('upload/news/'.$filename);
        if(intval($size) >= 1024 AND $width >= 40) {
            $filename = $filename;
        } else {
            unlink('upload/news/'.$filename);
            $filename = ''; 
        }
```

**...**